# StratifiedKFold TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for argument 'n_splits'

Tags: python, scikit-learn

This is my imports

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.mixture import GaussianMixture
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold

iris = datasets.load_iris()
```

was folds then change it to splits but error below appear

```
indices = StratifiedKFold(iris.target, n_splits=5)

train_index, test_index = next(iter(indices))

X_train = iris.data[train_index]
y_train = iris.target[train_index]

X_test = iris.data[test_index]
y_test = iris.target[test_index]
```

```
TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for argument 'n_splits'
```

Comment: I think you have a lot of unused imports in your import block which might confuse some people

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as per the [documnentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedKFold.html), you first need to initialize your `StratifiedKFold` object with n_splits and then use the `skf.get_n_splits` method so your code becomes:

```
skf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=5)

X = iris.data
y = iris.target 
for train_index, test_index in skf.split(X, y):
    print("TRAIN:", train_index, "TEST:", test_index)
    X_train, X_test = X[train_index], X[test_index]
    y_train, y_test = y[train_index], y[test_index]
```

Comment: Thank you so much Antoine it worked and ill fix the imports also , i really appreciate your help .

Comment: your welcome. If this worked for you could you approve the answer to tell the next person. Also you should check this [doc](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) by stack overflow but it seems saying thank you is not encouraged by the stack overflow community (also new so not sure )